# How clever is the python interpreter?

Tags: python

Probably a stupid question, but I am wondering in general, and if anyone knows, how much foresight the Python interpreter has, specifically in the field of regular expressions and text parsing.

Suppose my code at some point looks like this:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', ... ]

if 'g' in list: print(mylist.index('g'))
```

is there any safer way to do this with a while loop or similar. I mean, will the index be looked up with a second parsing from the beginning or are the two g's (in the above line) the same thing in Python's mind?

Comment: This isn't "parsing" so much as it is "searching".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try is better option to find the index of element in list.
try:
    print(mylist.index('g'))
except ValueError:
    print "value not in list"
    pass

Answer (score 4):

It'll do the lookup both times. If it's worth it (for, say, a very big list), use `try`:

```
try:
    print(mylist.index('g'))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

The result of the containment check is not cached, and so the index will need to be discovered anew. And the dynamic nature of Python makes implicit caching of such a thing unreliable since the `__contains__()` method may mutate the object (although it would be a violation of several programming principles to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will result in two lookups, first to determine if 'g' is in the list and second to find the index. Python won't try to consolidate them into a single lookup. If you're worried about efficiency you can use a dictionary instead of a list which will make both lookups O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a dict to look up. Something like this:

```
mydict = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(mylist)}
```

The overhead of creating the `dict` won't be worthwhile unless you are doing a few such lookups on the same `list`

Answer (score 0):

yeah it will be looked up twice, the python interpreter doesn't cache instructions, though I've being wondering if its possible (for certain things), if this is an issue, then you can use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) or [dicts](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) both of which have constant look up time.

Either way it seems you are [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html?highlight=lbyl#term-lbyl), in python we tend to [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html?highlight=lbyl#term-eafp) so its quite common to wrap such things in `try ... except` blocks